# How can we know the number of users for which the FCM notification is sent successfully or not

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In C# i am calling a Restful service to send notification to mobile device using Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM).
I am sending notification to a Topic.I want to know how many users it is successfully sent to, who are subscribed to this topic.

I am using following Post API.

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
 { 
"to" : "/topics/testdesktop_51to75",
"time_to_live" : 60,
"data":{
"alertId": "",
"alertTypeId": "",
"detailUrl": "",
"isFeatured": "",
"description":" ",
"payLoad": "",
"publishDate": "",
"title": ""
}
}

but in response i am getting only message id.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a message to a topic, in which case the response from the FCM server merely indicates whether the messages was received correctly by the server. The fanning out of the message to the tokens that are subscribed to that topic happens afterwards, and no data about the number of devices it was delivered to is returns in the initial response.

If you want to learn more about the number of tokens that the message was sent to, how long that so-called fan-out took, and how many deliveries were successful, you can do so by connecting the FCM delivery data to BigQuery. For more on that have a look at [Understanding message delivery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#count_messages_send_to_a_topic_or_campaign_from_the_notifications_console) in the Firebase documentation. I also recommend reading the blog post [Life of a message from FCM to the device](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/02/life-of-a-message.html).